# When data is entered into a cell, another piece of data is automatically entered into an adjoining cell

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-2007, excel-formula

I'm filling in my overtime form at work, and am learning Excel as I go. One thing I'm trying to achieve is when I enter data into a cell on a particular row (specifying that I did overtime on that date), the start time of that overtime (always 17:00) will automatically be entered into the next cell in the row.

If there is no data in the cell, then the next cell with remain empty.

I am using Excel 2007.

Answer (score 1):

Try this formula, placed at the B1 cell: =IF(A1="";"";A1-"17:00")

On "A1" place the time you left work.

It will display the aomunt of overtime you've done on that day. If there is no time input it will display nothing ("").